# Trying to use readme.md file as main page file in Doxygen results in blank

Tags: markdown, doxygen, readme

I am trying to use .md file as main page file for Doxygen generated HTML documentation. I provide path to directory, where source code resides as well as path to readme file at the input tab. I also provide readme.md file name at the USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE, but after generating Doxy, I get blank main page, going to related pages and clicking on _README opens this up:
[image]

Am I doing something wrong or forgot to check some other parameters?

**UPDATE:**
I am using Doxygen version 1.9.6. Here are all the settings that I have changed:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Update2:** Here are run configurations of Doxygen
[image]

And here is content of README file, at first I am just trying to get simple phrase, of course original text has a lot more useful information.

[image]

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Please add a small example and the doxygen settings different from the default settings (i.e. the result of `doxygen -x Doxyfile`) and add it to the question.

Comment: I added all the settings that I have changed as well as the version that I am using

Comment: Please: in the doxygen wizard please go to the run tab, set the "condensed" checkbox and hit the "show configuration" and show the result in your question

Comment: Also add the content of Readme.md (there might be more files involved in your project but this is not clear from the question) best is to provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: my readme file is located inside source code folder, could that somehow be the problem?

Comment: Please never use images to show code (as one cannot cut and paste it). The README.md place might be a problem, just try to specify the full path with the `USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE`. On the page with the run tab there is also the field  "Specify the working directory from which doxygen will run" what does this say?